# cannot find Publish Items in Add Project Output Group

Tags: c#, setup-project

trying to create the setup .exe so user can download my project on their comptuer, I'm following instructions on how to it, however, when I click on teh "Add Project Output Group" i'm not seeing the "Publish Item" option in the dropdown, Am i missing something?

[prjoect items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9WcR.png)

"Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.5.5
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.5.5+33627.172
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09037

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA188
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.5.320.55692
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.5.320.55692
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   4.5.2-3.23171.7+d17f741546fad2786cbd6394d08619544e53a36d
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.22336.2
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Node.js Tools   1.5.50105.3 Commit Hash:882de61a7c99ae988d4c62029301292a3e0b1d56
Adds support for developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   6.5.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Python - Profiling support   17.0.22336.2
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python with Pylance   17.0.22336.2
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.5.2.2316603+9f1b6856460af1e592d387ebef416eadddac453f
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.2.40120.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20105.2003
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.5.2-3.23171.7+d17f741546fad2786cbd6394d08619544e53a36d
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.5.0-beta.23053.5+794b7c259d9646a7eb685dad865aa27da7940a21
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the framework version.
For .NET, the support is only on versions .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5.0 or .NET 6.0

font: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/910711/where-can-i-find-publish-items